How to get the real IP address in Nuxt 3 using an API endpoint?
I'm working with Nuxt 3 and have created a server-side API endpoint to retrieve the client's real local IP address. However, when I send a request from the client-side to this API, I always get 127.0.0.1 as the response, even when the request is made from different devices.
Here is the code for my server/api/getIP.ts file:
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const headers = getRequestHeaders(event);
  const forwarded = headers["x-forwarded-for"]?.split(",")[0];
  const ip =
    forwarded || headers["x-real-ip"] || event.node.req.socket.remoteAddress;

  return {
    ip,
  };
});

And the client-side request:
const testHandle = async (s) => {
  const getIP = await $fetch("/api/getIP");
  console.log("client respond = ", getIP);
};

No matter what device or network I use, the response always returns 127.0.0.1 as the IP address.
I suspect this may be an issue with how the IP address is being forwarded or read, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.
How can I get the real local IP address (rather than 127.0.0.1) in Nuxt 3?
